# When are "mixed teams" allowed in Olympics?

Tags: olympics

Reading about the olympics I found that sometimes it was allowed "mixed teams". Now for countries with deep bonds this might make sense, but mixed teams from countries like Great Britain and France? Or Cuba-United States?

when is this possible?

Comment: A source would be great I guess, you're not talking about Eng/Sco/N-Irl into team GB mix are you?

Comment: The Olympic Games are a competition among countries and when was it allowed in the past? I have never heard of it.

Comment: http://www.topendsports.com/events/summer/countries/mixed-team.htm

Comment: Are you talking about the Olympics in 1900 and asking if this will be possible in the future?

Comment: No, I'm talking about when it is or was allowed

Comment: which are or were the regulations for it to be allowed

Comment: As answered below, it is not possible unless the Olympic Charter is revised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Olympic Charter](https://stillmed.olympic.org/Documents/olympic_charter_en.pdf) clearly states in II. Participation in the Olympic Games as follows:

> 41. Nationality of competitors
>
> Any competitor in the Olympic Games must be a **national of the country** of the NOC (National Olympic Committee) which is entering such competitor.

and

> 44. Invitations and entries
>
> The invitations to take part in the Olympic Games shall be sent out by the IOC to all NOCs one year before the opening ceremony.

Therefore, other nationals will not be able to compete together with nationals of a country unless they receive citizenship in the country.